# How to add a space between two strings using StringBuilder in Java?

Tags: java, string

i am practicing `StringBuilder` in java and I want to know that if I want to add a space in two strings what method should i use?

```
public class StringPractice {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringBuilder buffer1 = new StringBuilder();
    String id = "333";
    String name = "Abdur Rehman Khalid";
    buffer1.append(id);
    buffer1.append(name);
    System.out.println(buffer1.toString());
}

}
```

Output I get:

```
333Abdur Rehman Khalid
```

Expected output:

```
333 Abdur Rehman Khalid.
```

Comment: buffer1.append(" " + name);

Comment: Just append a space to it as `buffer1.append(" ");`

Comment: Append a space between appending id and appending name.

Answer (score 5):

If your are using Java 8, you can use the [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) class:

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" ");
joiner.add(id).add(name);
String joinedString = joiner.toString();
```

Otherwise use `append(" ")` on your `StringBuilder` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 buffer1.append(id).append(" ").append(name)
```

String builder append method returns instance of the same object (this), so you can have multiple appends in single line.

Answer (score 1):

Simply,

```
buffer1.append(id);
buffer1.append(" ");
buffer1.append(name);
```

Or you can use method chaining rather than use three line.